# Making a patch a link in matlab?

Tags: matlab, hyperlink, patch

I have asked several questions about making links on images in matlab, but I want to be able to make a patch a link. I tried the code I posted below but that didnt work. Any ideas on how to make this work?

```
 patch([x2(i) x2(i+1) x2(i+1) x2(i)],[y3(j) y3(j) y3(j+1) y3(j+1)],[-0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01],'r','FaceAlpha' ,.4,'EdgeColor','none','ButtonDownFcn', ['winopen(''' file(j,i) ''');']);

function [filePath] = file( x, y )
    filePath = strcat('C:\Documents and Settings\Sentinelle\My Documents\Prostate_082_31\sl5_knt1\sl5_',num2str(x),'-',num2str(y),'.ps');
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, callbacks are called with two input arguments, the handle to an object and a usually empty `eventdata`. This might lead to the error. Try this instead of `['winopen(''' file(j,i) ''');']`:

```
@(u,v)winopen(@()file(j,i))
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `@()` before `file(j,i)`.

Comment: @gnovice: You're right. Still, I like to make it clear to myself that `file` is a function call and not an array in this context (because I wouldn't have guessed from the name).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example (just adjust the paths of files to something that actually exist):

```
BASE_DIR = 'C:\path\to\directory';
fcn = @(x,y) fullfile( BASE_DIR , sprintf('file_%d-%d.txt',x,y) );

patch([-1 -1 1 1], [-1 1 -1 1], 'r', ...
    'ButtonDownFcn',{@(o,e,f)winopen(f), fcn(2,1)})
axis([-2 2 -2 2])
title('Click the shape to open file...')
```

[image]

Comment: A simpler callback would be: `@(o,e) winopen(fcn(2,1))`

Comment: true, I just wanted to givr a different way of passing callbacks than what @Jonas showed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the position of the patch it was positioned behind the image [-0.01 -0.01 -0.01 -0.01]. The links were being covered up by the image. I changed the code to [0 0 0 0] and this works how I want it to.

```
patch([x2(i) x2(i+1) x2(i+1) x2(i)],[y3(j) y3(j) y3(j+1) y3(j+1)],[0 0 0 0],'r','FaceAlpha' ,.4,'EdgeColor','none','ButtonDownFcn', ['winopen(''' file(j,i) ''');']);
```